# Two dependent fields bootstrap datepicker calendar coach and KnockoutJs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-datepicker

Regards,
I have a requirement in the use of knockoutJs with bootstrap datepicker. You need to have date range.

Requirements:
I have two datepickers.
- The first datepicker gets the value for the field since.
- The second datepicker gets the value for the field up.
- You need to get the difference in days between the two dates.

**Flow**

1. When the page loads, the datepicker with the field from start to the current date.
2. The second datepicker (to field) starts empty.
3. Each time, we selected a date (from field), the value of the second field (to field) is reset.
4. When selecting a date (from field), the available dates (to field) are those between (from field) forward.
5. Start the flow from step 3.

**Calculation Date**

- Every time there dates in their respective fields, calculate the difference in days.

The fiddle: [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1ag44j9/)

```
function viewModelCustom() {
  var self = this;

  var today = new Date();
  var todayFormat = moment(today).format('DD/MM/YYYY');

  self.StartDate = ko.observable(todayFormat);
  self.EndDate = ko.observable(todayFormat);

  self.diffDays = ko.computed(function() {
    var result;
    var start = moment(self.StartDate(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
    var end = moment(self.EndDate(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');

    result = Math.abs(start.diff(end, "days")) + 1;

    return result;
  });


  ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      //initialize datepicker with some optional options
      var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {

        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      };
      $(element).datepicker(options);

      //when a user changes the date, update the view model
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
          value(event.date);
        }
      });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
      //when the view model is updated, update the widget
      if (widget) {
        widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        widget.setValue();
      }
    }
  };

}


ko.applyBindings(new viewModelCustom());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are computing moment.js dates using the wrong input format.

https://jsfiddle.net/z5h9d0oq/1/

```
self.diffDays = ko.computed(function() {
    var result;
    var start = moment(self.StartDate(), 'ddd MMM DD YYYY');
    var end = moment(self.EndDate(), 'ddd MMM DD YYYY');

    result = end.diff(start, "days");

    return result;
});
```

To check the input format by a form, use

```
console.info(self.StartDate());
```

and the input actually was

```
 Tue Jun 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve one problem, i update mi fiddle. One question more, At what point is that the date format changes? I try to catch, and dont know when that is happen.

Comment: When a date is selected. So start with moment with no format